# avoid changing of layer names while exporting rasterbrick as tiff

Tags: r

I'm creating a raster brick and trying to export it as a tif file. However the exported file does not have the layer names I saved. How do I fix this?

```
input raster
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 361, 381, 137541, 31  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 63.95, 102.05, 3.95, 40.05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :    X01.10.17,    X02.10.17,    X03.10.17,    X04.10.17,    X05.10.17,    X06.10.17,    X07.10.17,    X08.10.17,    X09.10.17,    X10.10.17,    X11.10.17,    X12.10.17,    X13.10.17,    X14.10.17,    X15.10.17, ... 
min values :  -0.09161241,  -0.09319755,  -0.09485003,  -0.10156322,  -0.10068546,  -0.10197223,  -0.10647616,  -0.09454857,  -0.09112226,  -0.09484527,  -0.13098687,  -0.10653945,  -0.12956281,  -0.17043509,  -0.14697702, ... 
max values : 0.0019110237, 0.0013544868, 0.0015650620, 0.0016381089, 0.0015431716, 0.0011034622, 0.0013723321, 0.0015710103, 0.0009461852, 0.0007710628, 0.0014798801, 0.0009300054, 0.0010204219, 0.0013285516, 0.0006675598, ...
```

layer name include date month year.
However following are the layer names in the exported raster

```
    outfile <- writeRaster(input raster, filename=paste0("G:\\My Drive\\DATA\\",fname),
                         format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE,full.names=T)
  l<-brick("K:\\try\\2017-10.tif")
> l
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 361, 381, 137541, 31  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 63.95, 102.05, 3.95, 40.05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : 2017-10.tif 
names      :      layer.1,      layer.2,      layer.3,      layer.4,      layer.5,      layer.6,      layer.7,      layer.8,      layer.9,     layer.10,     layer.11,     layer.12,     layer.13,     layer.14,     layer.15, ... 
min values :  -0.09161241,  -0.09319755,  -0.09485003,  -0.10156322,  -0.10068546,  -0.10197223,  -0.10647616,  -0.09454857,  -0.09112226,  -0.09484527,  -0.13098687,  -0.10653945,  -0.12956281,  -0.17043509,  -0.14697702, ... 
max values : 0.0019110237, 0.0013544868, 0.0015650620, 0.0016381089, 0.0015431716, 0.0011034622, 0.0013723321, 0.0015710103, 0.0009461852, 0.0007710628, 0.0014798801, 0.0009300054, 0.0010204219, 0.0013285516, 0.0006675598, ...
```

I want the earlier file name for further analysis.

Comment: please edit your code to make your example self-contained and reproducible. That is, use some example data created with code, or use a file that ships with R.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by using `terra::writeRaster` instead of `raster::writeRaster`

Comment: I tried :rnc <- `rnc <- terra::writeRaster(brk, filename=file.path( "netCDF.nc"), format="CDF", overwrite=TRUE)` however the output still has new names: names      :       X1,       X2,       X3,       X4,       X5,       X6,       X7,       X8,       X9,      X10,      X11,      X12,      X13,      X14,      X15, ...

Comment: If `brk` is a RasterBrick than you are effectively still using `raster::writeRaster`

Comment: understandable. I eventually ended up using .grd format to export. However I'll keep your suggestion for next time.